# Customize subtitles for QuickTime + Perian

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, quicktime, subtitles

How do I customize the display of subtitles (e.g. font, size, color, outline, drop shadow) in QuickTime + Perian? I've seen articles on how to do it but it requires Jubler to edit the subtitles. Is there a straightforward way to customize the subtitles within QuickTime or Perian?

If there isn't any, what are other alternatives? VLC can't display drop shadows, and can customize the outline. I'm looking for other ways where I'll only have to use QuickTime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most reliable video player under OS X for me has been [Movist](http://code.google.com/p/movist/). It's exceedingly stable, can use either Quicktime or FFmpeg like Perian, and comes with absolutely fantastic subtitle support:
[image: Screenshot of Movist's extensive subtitles]

Answer (score 0):

VLC (or at least VLC 2.0.0) also has advanced options for customizing subtitles.

[image]

There's no way to change the outline or shadow color. The vertical offset can be changed in the Subtitles/OSD section.